# represent a class in the order that was shown in init, without hardcoding

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

In one method, I parse a CSV file. On each iteration, I make an object out of that entry. Given that the object represents a row in that CSV file, it would be much easier to read if it were in order, rather than just `return self.__dict__`

```
class Student:
  def __init__(self, name, grade, classes):
    self.name = name
    self.grade = grade
    self.classes = classes
  def __repr__(self):
    return #ordered version of self
```

the CSV function:

```
with open(arguments.csv, 'rb') as csv_file:
  csv_data = csv.reader(csv_file)
  data = [Student(*row) for row in csv_data]
```

expected output (with "pretty printing" included, matching the original init):

```
Student:
  name: 'Crow',
  grade: 1,
  classes: ['pecking', 'cawing', 'scavenging', 'advanced film theory']
Student:
  name: 'Odin',
  grade: 9999,
  classes: ['Norse Mythology', 'Orithonology']
```

How do you represent it in an ordered fashion without hard coding it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `__init__` method has the names ordered; they happen to match your `__dict__` keys, so you could use those:

```
import inspect

class Student(object):
    def __init__(self, name, grade, classes):
        self.name = name
        self.grade = grade
        self.classes = classes
    def __repr__(self):
        return '{}\n{}'.format(type(self).__name__,
            '\n'.join(['  {}: {!r}'.format(name, getattr(self, name))
                       for name in inspect.getargspec(self.__init__).args[1:]]))
```

Here, [`inspect.getargspec()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html#inspect.getargspec) returns the signature information for the `self.__init__` method; `.args` is the positional arguments. Slicing it to `[1:]` skips the first argument, `self`.

Demo:

```
>>> Student('Crow', 1, ['pecking', 'cawing', 'scavenging', 'advanced film theory'])
Student
  name: 'Crow'
  grade: 1
  classes: ['pecking', 'cawing', 'scavenging', 'advanced film theory']
```

Comment: ah, martijin, you are truly a genius

Comment: @crow No one doubts it, but use words feeding pride sparingly

Answer (score 1):

I usually prefer declaration over introspection :

```
import itertools
class Student(object):

    columns = ('name', 'grade', 'classes')

    def __init__(self, *row):
        self.row = _,_,_ = row # Aaaaah, dragons !

    def __getattr__(self, key):
        if key in self.columns:
            return self.row[self.columns.index(key)]

    def __repr__(self):
        return '{}\n{}'.format(
                type(self).__name__,
                '\n'.join(('  {}: {!r}'.format(*item)
                    for item in itertools.izip(self.columns, self.row) ))
                )
```

You could even add the *generic* touch to it :

```
import itertools
class Row(object):
    columns = ()
    def __init__(self, *row):
        if len(row) != len(self.columns):
            raise TypeError('{}() takes {} argument'.format(
                    type(self).__name__, len(self.columns)))
        self.row = row
    def __getattr__(self, key):
        if key in self.columns:
            return self.row[self.columns.index(key)]
    def __repr__(self):
        return '{}\n{}'.format(
                type(self).__name__,
                '\n'.join(('  {}: {!r}'.format(*item)
                    for item in itertools.izip(self.columns, self.row) ))
                )
class Student(Row):
    columns = ('name','grade','classes')
```